# How to embed mxd file to html/php

Tags: maps, arcgis

I have arcgis mxd file, I dont know how to use arcgis, i just have .mxd file and need to embed into html/php to make a maps access via browser ? Maybe using iframe or arcgis have tool to convert ?

Answer (score 1):

Mxd files are published using [ArcGIS for Server](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisserver). But it's not free.
I think there is no other way to directly publish mxd on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you'd want to host an MXD on the web, but I'm assuming you want to put an interactive map on a website? You can publish services to ArcGIS for Server or ArcGIS Online if you have access to that. Otherwise you can upload a static map. Create a PDF, JPEG, PNG, etc by going to File > Export after opening the MXD file.